# Read multiple JSONs from single REST Service response and put to Database Table - Talend

Tags: json, database, rest, talend

[image]I have searched a lot but not found exact slution.
I have a REST service, in response of which I get rows and each row in a JSON, as given bellow:

```
{"event":"click1","properties":{ "time":"2 dec 2018","clicks":29,"parent":"jbar","isLast":"NO"}}
{"event":"click2","properties":{ "time":"2 dec 2018","clicks":35,"parent":"jbar3","isLast":"NO"}}
{"event":"click3","properties":{ "time":"2 dec 2018","clicks":10,"parent":"jbar2","isLast":"NO"}}
{"event":"click4","properties":{ "time":"2 dec 2018","clicks":9,"parent":"jbar1","isLast":"YES"}}
```

Each row is a JSON (all are similar to each other). I have a database table having all those fields as columns. I wanted to loop through these and upload all data in Talend. What I have tried is following:

```
tRestClient--tNormalize--tExtractJsonFields--tOracleOutput
```

and provided loop criteria and mapping in tExtractJsonFields component but it is not working and throwing me error saying "**json can not be null or empty[image]**"
Need help in doing that.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @Abhishek I have updated the question. I am getting "json can not be null or empty" Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your webservice returns multiple json objects in the response, it's not valid json but rather a json document.
You need to break it into individual json objects.
You can add a `tNormalize` between `tRESTClient` and `tExtractJsonFields`, and normalize the json document on "\n" character.
The error "`json can not be null or empty`" is due to an error in your Jsonpath queries. You have to set the loop query to "`$`", and reference the json properties using "`event`", "`properties.time`"

Comment: Thanks your solution took me one step ahead and I used *tNormalize* and get individual JSON objects. Now my job structure looks like:

`tRestClient--tNormalize--tExtractJsonFields--tOracleOutput`

but now I am getting **json can not be null or empty** and zero rows flow from tExtractJsonFields to tOracleOutput. 

I am using mapping in tExtractJsonFields so as to map on columns of table also I am using loop criteria as ("") in it.. can u help?

Comment: Finally I got the solution by using 2 steps:
1) added tNormalize after tRestClient
2) loop criteria to "$" in  tExtractJsonFields

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I've missed your comment. I'm guessing you got it to work ?
Probably by adding "$" as the loop query, and using "event", "properties.time" for the columns query ?

Comment: I've just seen your comment where you say you got the solution. It's as I guessed :)
I'll update my answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks @iMezour 
One last thing that I need help. How can I take care of primary key column value while inserting data into table. Can I generate unique ids in talend and then insert inti table column?

Comment: It's better to let the database handle the primary key. You could just define an auto incremented primary key column for your table, and not map the column in Talend, this way the value will be auto incremented by the database itself

Comment: Just one last thing what component should I use if I want to use tRestClient with different query parameters (in url as GET request) just to get different types of data (based upon parameters specified) @iMezouar

Answer (score 0):

could you try this :

In your **tExtractJsonFields**, configure the property readBy to ***JsonPath without loop***